# JavaScript not working - apache2 + Ubuntu

Tags: php, javascript, apache2

Setup: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.7 with Suhosin-Patch configured

/etc/debian_version shows "squeeze/sid".

Copied a javascript ts_picker.js file to /usr/lib/cgi-bin (the configured CGI directory in apache conf files). All my PHP programs are in the same directory as well.

Tried running a simple PHP script which refers the ts_picker.js file within a `<script src>` tag in the `<HEAD>`.

But no javascript works. Apache error.log shows:

```
[Wed Apr 13 19:05:41 2011] [error] [client 10.0.0.37] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/ts_picker.js' failed, referer: http://10.0.27.200/cgi-bin/js.php
[Wed Apr 13 19:05:41 2011] [error] [client 10.0.0.37] Premature end of script headers: ts_picker.js, referer: http://10.0.27.200/cgi-bin/js.php
```

Tried checking for permissions on the .js: they are 755, just as with all my PHP scripts.

Tried grepping 'javascript' and 'js' recursively under /etc/apache2 and found nothing except a DEFLATE entry:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.conf:          # AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript application/ecmascript
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/deflate.conf:          # AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript application/ecmascript
```

Additionally, if I open the source of the PHP's HTML output on the browser and if I click on the ts_picker.js link there, it shows a 500 Internal error.

I am really stuck at this point and unable to do much. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This belongs on http://serverfault.com/. This is a server configuration question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript files are statically served assets - they are not executed by your webserver, but by the client browser. So they should not be set as executable, nor should they be in a scripts folder like /cgi-bin: as a result apache is trying to execute these js files when requested, as opposed to just serving them back. You need to move your js files to wherever static resources live, and set them to read-only.

Comment: Richard, that was very clear. Thanks for the explanation. I've moved the .js to another folder and everything works as expected.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya - please feel to mark correct if my answer solved your issue :)